# CakePHP 2.0 Ajax login

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have the following method which allows a user to login into my application:

```
public function login()
{   
    if($this->Auth->user())
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Already logged in...'), 'default', array(), 'auth');

        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','home'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
    {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';

        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

It allows a user to login either using a post request or via an ajax request. However with regards to the ajax requests how do I pass the results back using JSON? So for example if the user enters the wrong details pass back an error message?

I have the jQuery AJAX already setup so I just need to do some extra logic in the success method to deal with the return which will either show the error message from the server or do a redirect again based on the return from the server.

e.g.

```
    $('form').live('submit', function (event) {

    // Declare the form
    var form = $(this);

    // Stop the form from doing a native postback
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the data from the form
    var data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: data,
        success: function (responseHtml) {

            // If correct login details
            if(success){
                 window.location.href('INSERT LOCATION TO REDIRECT TO FROM SERVER');
            } else {        
                 alert('INSERT MESSAGE FROM THE SERVER');
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert('Error!');

        }

    });

});
```

Can anyone help? I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and all of the tutorials I have seen on the net and on here have either been outdated or much too long-winded for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: you need to use the following php code

```
    if ($this->Auth->login())  
    {  
         $arr = array("login" => "true" , "redirect" => "/redirect_url");
         echo json_encode($arr);
    }  
    else  
    {  
         $arr = array("login" => "false" , "error" => "Invalid Login Credentials");
         echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

on the javascript side you need to modify your javascript to handle json values using jQuery.getJSON. example of jQuery.getJSON is availabe here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

use this jQuery code

```
<script  type="text/javascript">


  $.getJSON("login.php", function(data) {
                  if(data.login)
                  {
                      //redirect user with data.redirect
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      //display error   with data.error
                  }
   })


</script>
```

Comment: That's not very flexible and it's not passing back the redirect link. Hence why I wanted to use JSON so I could pass multiple variables.

Comment: you can use an array in php and then use json_encode($array) to convert the array to json

Comment: Care to show an example of that? and then how I would use this in the JavaScript success call to decide whether it was an error or not and then do the relevant action.

Comment: i have added jquery json example as well